# When using extract function from terra package in R, only cells within the contour are filtered, not within the polygon itself

Tags: r, polygon, r-sp, terra

I have polygon image as png file.
I changed this png polygon to spatialPolygon in R.

However, when I extract the cells within the spatialpolygon, only cells within the contour are filtered, not within the polygon itself.

The reason I guess is that the spatialpolygon contour has the width, so only cells within the contour are obtained.

How can I fix this situation?

[image: Spatialpolygon]

[image: Filetered cells]

```
# Load PNG image
img <- readPNG("../polygon.png")

# Convert image to grayscale if it's color (assuming RGB color here)
if (dim(img)[3] == 3) {
  img <- 0.299*img[,,1] + 0.587*img[,,2] + 0.114*img[,,3]
}

# Convert to matrix
img <- matrix(img, nrow = dim(img)[1], ncol = dim(img)[2])

# Create a raster from the matrix
r <- raster(img)

# Set the extent of the raster based on your corner points
xmin <- min(11810, 12230, 12350, 12220) # smallest x-coordinate
xmax <- max(11810, 12230, 12350, 12220) # largest x-coordinate
ymin <- min(53440, 53290, 53420, 53540) # smallest y-coordinate
ymax <- max(53440, 53290, 53420, 53540) # largest y-coordinate

extent(r) <- c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

spat_pol <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x == 1})
```

Comment: Can you include "polygon.png"? And show how you got to the other images? That is show your complete code not just some part of it and plots that come from nowhere. And how is "extract" used here?